# How to embed standard page in vf page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, cross-domain

My requirement is to embed standard opportunity home page to visual force page,

[image]

I have tried using iframe but i don't want to show sidebar and header of standard page.

For removing the sidebar and header i tried javascript to display it none but it is violating the cross-domain rule of browser security.

Any work-around/suggestions would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a parameter that sf uses but claims is not officially supported.  Your iframe src add as follows: /006/o?isdtp=vw.  Good luck.

UPDATE:
I tried creating a simple page to do this, and tried the "lt" parameter (the only other one I know about).

```
<apex:page >
     <apex:sectionHeader title="Test Opportunities"/>
     <apex:pageblock >
          <apex:iframe src="/006/o?isdtp=lt"/>
     </apex:pageblock>
</apex:page>
```

For me, the links are not underlined, but they are "click-able".

Comment: Great!!!, it just solved my problem, but i have a question, what is isdtp=vw?

Comment: It is one of a set of URL parameters that SF uses to control the way the UI is presented to the user.  As I mentioned it is not officially supported, but lots of people use it.

Comment: your solution is not working when i deployed it to production. Links in the iframe not working, when i am clicking any opportunity name it is not going to page of the opportunity.

Comment: Sorry about that.  The vw is for service console.  Try isdtp=mn instead.

Comment: Sorry jimRae, nothing is working, isdtp=mn also has same problem.

Comment: Sorry it is still not working..  Maybe we should go back to the beginning.  What kind of vf page are you trying to embed this in?  What is the specific use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [apex:enhancedList](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm) to insert that standard opp page to the VF page. The sidebar can be removed with the apex:page parameter `sidebar="false"`, and the header just with a javascript:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">

<script>
    document.getElementById('AppBodyHeader').style.display = 'none';
</script>

<apex:enhancedList type="Opportunity" height="600" rowsPerPage="50" id="OppList" />

</apex:page>
```

It will looks like this then:

[image]

Comment: @mastOr please see my question, in screen shot there is recent opportunities, reports, quarterly summery i want all sections included in page, your solution is good, but that not includes other sections, please suggest how to get other things too.